# Is it possible to change the route depending on query value

Tags: php, symfony, routes

In my routing.yml

```
acme_top_homepage:
    pattern:  /{date}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeTopBundle:Default:index,date:"" }

acme_who_homepage:  
    pattern:  /mailForm
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeTopBundle:Default:mailForm }
```

I would like to route like this `http://test.com/2013-04-16` and `http://test.com/2013-06-15` go to 'index' and `http://test.com/mailForm` go to 'mailForm'.

If I would use Regular Expression,I was happy.

```
/{date} -> /{\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d}
```

Is it possible to change the route depending on query value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just add a requirement regex, and the route will only match if the regex matches:

```
pattern:    /{date}
defaults:   { _controller: AcmeTopBundle:Default:index }
requirements:
    date:   \d{4}-\d\d-\d\d
```

If the route doesn't match then the routing will keep going through until the first route which does match.